# Embed google spreadsheet in HTML (narrow result)

Tags: html, css, iframe, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet in google drive. I've published it to the web, and pasted the "correct code" on my website.

```
<iframe src="linkToTheFile"></iframe>
```

In my case

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hIs40J7W5OfhplAokR3duEdJUY2rXEjv9muFawcfRS0/pub?embedded=true"></iframe>
```

as Google instructions say https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965?hl=sv

But this displays too narrow. This is how it looks on the website. (I have pasted two documents there)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

just add width="600" height="600" before the link (you can customise the width and height and bobs your uncle!

e.g. `<iframe width="600" height="600" src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hIs40J7W5OfhplAokR3duEdJUY2rXEjv9muFawcfRS0/pub?embedded=true"></iframe>`